# Creating a custom layout without the App action/status bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

For starters any app created in the IDE comes with an App header, how could I go about creating a layout without the action bar?

Comment: What is "an App header"?

Comment: The section where the application title shows on top of the main activity.

Comment: do you mean the ActionBar ?

Comment: set the no action bar theme

Comment: To clarify, I meant the action/status bar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the activity class you can set the layout to full screen.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Also, if you want it throughout the app you can update the manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Yes. After `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`